# OpenGL 360 degrees light source

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I'm trying to create light which is illuminating in every direction. Currently I'm using that code:

```
const GLfloat light1_ambient[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light1_diffuse[] = { 0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light1_specular[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light1_position[] = { 0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_AMBIENT, light1_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_DIFFUSE, light1_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPECULAR, light1_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 180.0f);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT1, GL_POSITION, light1_position);
```

There is code for ground:

```
for(int i = -50; i < 50; i++)
{
    for(int j = -50; j < 50; j++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(i,0,j);
        glVertex3f(i,0,j+1);
        glVertex3f(i+1,0,j+1);
        glVertex3f(i+1,0,j);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

It gives me this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1Jtc.png

Which looks like it is illuminating in 180 degress. (when I change GL_SPOT_CUTOFF to 90 it looks the same)
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong or maybe that is how it should work?

### **OK, I know what was the problem I haven't set normal for ground.**

Comment: Can you show how yours floor mesh is done?

Comment: @TomásBadan Added code for creating ground to the post.

Comment: Are you setting the parameters for the correct light (`GL_LIGHT1` vs `GL_LIGHT0`)?

Comment: Ahhhh FFP. Dont use it anymore. Its deprecated and should not used anymore. Use shaders and vertex buffers!